# Как преобразовать столбец из БД в строку?

Tags: php, mysql, запрос, sendmail

Получаем пароль пользователя из БД по критериям(почта и логин)...
Его нужно преобразовать в строку, что-бы отправить на почту пользователю(это типо скрипт для восстановления пароля, если человек забыл).

Выдаёт ошибку:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be
>   converted to string

.

Вот код запроса:

```
$passUp = $mysqli -> query('SELECT `pass_1` FROM `users` WHERE mail = "'.$mail.'"');

$text = $passUp;
```

И потом переменная `$text` отправляется функцией `mail()` по всем параметрам, там ошибок нет.

Comment: Может немного не в тему, но... вы храните пароли пользователей в **чистом виде**?.. Я уже не говорю о том, что Вы вклеиваете $mail в запрос вручную. Для чего вообще создатели mysqli и pdo пыжились с подготовленными выражениями... Зря только время потратили)

Comment: изучайте fetch функции, вот пример http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php кроме выполнения запроса к бд надо также его представить в читаемом формате, типа массива.

Comment: Александр, пароли храню под шифром(sha256) в БД. Про подготовленные выражения ни разу не слышал, язык только неделю назад начал изучать)

Comment: Где мать вашу `fetch()` результатов ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил свою проблему так:

```
$passUp = $mysqli -> query('SELECT `pass_1` FROM `users` WHERE mail = "'.$mail.'"');
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($passUp);
$_SESSION["pass"] = $row["pass_1"];
```

Может и не очень правильно, но работает как я хотел)